# Java Testng unit test: Spring is not able to create object before BeforeSuite or BeforeTest

Tags: java, spring, testng

I have an unit test is working fine in it's current format. My unit test looks like:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:testContext.xml" })
public class DialPadMonitorTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    DialPadMonitor service;


    @BeforeSuite
    public void doBeforeSuite() {       
        System.out.println("Initializing suit.........");
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void doBeforeTest() {
        System.out.println("Initializing tests.........");
    }

    @Test()
    void testIfEasyToDial()
    {
        service.createDialAssociation();

        Assert.assertTrue(service.isNumberEasy(159658521));
        Assert.assertTrue(service.isNumberEasy(555555555));
        Assert.assertFalse(service.isNumberEasy(505555555));
        Assert.assertFalse(service.isNumberEasy(555555505));

        Assert.assertTrue(service.isNumberEasy(2547096));
        Assert.assertTrue(service.isNumberEasy(5547521));
        Assert.assertFalse(service.isNumberEasy(2806547));
        Assert.assertFalse(service.isNumberEasy(3558123));

    }

    @Test()
    void testIfAssociated()
    {
        service.createDialAssociation();

        Assert.assertTrue(service.isNoAssociated(3,3));
        Assert.assertTrue(service.isNoAssociated(3,6));
        Assert.assertFalse(service.isNoAssociated(3,9));

    }
}
```

Even though I am seeing the comments like

- System.out.println("Initializing suit.........");
- System.out.println("Initializing test.........");

Problem is that if I move service.createDialAssociation() into any of BeforeSuite or BeforeTest, I am getting null pointer exception.

Any insight on why am I getting the null pointer exception in that case and how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@BeforeMethod` instead of `@BeforeTest` because context is initialized that way. You can see it in a [Spring source file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/context/testng/AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure Spring context was loaded fully, add a method anotated with [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html)

> The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
 @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
 @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
 @Override
 protected void springTestContextPrepareTestInstance() throws Exception {
     super.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance();
 }
```

solves the issue. Note that this method springTestContextPrepareTestInstance should be executed before all @BeforeSuite methods. This can be achieved by placing it to a separate base class or by adding depenedsOn in others @BeforeSuite annotations.